# is it possible to remove all IFRAMEs from XML content acquired via JQUERY $.ajax?

Tags: ajax, jquery

I have a project where I am retrieving external XML (rss 2.0 feed) using $.ajax...

I have one particular node that contains a chunkk of HTML content which includes IFRAME content and I want to REMOVE that IFRAME before it is ever inserted in the DOM.  I thought about doing .replace() but the iframe tag is unknown and ever-changing...

Im retrieving this node as follows:

```
var articleContent = "<div id='content_" + listcount + "' class='arrContent'>" + $(this).find("content\\:encoded, encoded").text() + "</div>";
```

and then later I just .append() that variable 'articleContent' to a div on my page.

What Im trying to do is PRIOR to the .append() I want to remove ALL the IFRAME tag completely.

I tried doing

```
$(articleContent).not('iframe');
```

and

```
$(articleContent + ' iframe').remove();
```

but neither works...  how can I 'clean' all the  references OR SKIP over that before bringing the HTMl content in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this :

```
$(articleContent).not('iframe').appendTo("body");
```

Example :

http://jsbin.com/ocOkIfA/8/edit

**HOWEVER :**

If the iframe was **inside** the `div` ( I don't know your code ) -

```
var articleContent = "<div id='content' >sssss<iframe></iframe><p></p><iframe></iframe></div> ";
```

You *could* use this (*find*):

```
$(articleContent).find('iframe').remove().end().appendTo("body");
```

http://jsbin.com/ocOkIfA/11/edit

Comment: For any others who are looking to solve a similar issue:  2nd method worked perfectly.  many thanks @Royi Namir